# Hide extra y-tick labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have this plot and want to keep the red lines from the extra y-ticks but I don't want the labels at the side, as they are explained elsewhere and interfere with the normal axis ticks. Also a thick line would be perfect.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

my y-ticks settings:

```
extra y ticks       = {-0.5,0.5},
extra tick style={major grid style=red},
```

Comment: `extra y tick labels={}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for normal ticks, `extra y tick labels={}` will remove the labels for the extra ticks. For thicker red lines, use e.g. `major grid style={red, very thick}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ytick distance=1, % just for example
  grid,
  extra y ticks       = {-0.5,0.5},
  extra y tick labels={}, % remove labels for extra ticks
  extra tick style={
    major grid style={red, very thick} % for multiple settings, use a pair of braces
  },
]
\addplot {2*rnd -1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```